# Change map from div - google maps api - SAPUI5

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I'm developing a webapp with sapui5, that needs to use a map.
This is my scenario:

I have a view, called view1, which is my main wiew. Inside that view I have an input field(input1), and an icontabbar, with 4 different tabs.

The default tab is the first one, I need it as a requirement.
Now, the second tab of the incontabbar, corresponds to the map.
Input1 field, is the field corresponding to the autocomplete field for the map.

And here it becomes interesting, inside the tabs from the icontabbar, I have subviews, with its own controllers and view files (xml views).

View1 code: (update with full view1)

```
<mvc:View controllerName="WDC.controller.View1" 
xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" 
xmlns:core="sap.ui.core"
xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc" 
xmlns:f="sap.ui.layout.form"
displayBlock="true" 
xmlns="sap.m">
<App>
    <pages>
        <Page title="{i18n>title}">
            <f:SimpleForm id="SimpleFormToolbar">
                <f:content >

                    <Label class="labels" width="50%" id="label" text="Address" labelFor="input1"/>
                    <Input class="myInput" id="input1" width="50%" fieldWidth="100%" showSuggestion="true"/>
                </f:content>

            </f:SimpleForm>
            <IconTabBar>
                <items>
                    <IconTabFilter icon="sap-icon://employee" text="Data" id="iconTabBarData">
                        <mvc:XMLView viewName="WDC.view.view3"/>
                    </IconTabFilter>
                    <IconTabFilter icon="sap-icon://map" text="Map" id="mapTab" visible="true">             
                            <mvc:XMLView viewName="WDC.view.View2"/> // THIS VIEW IS NOT CREATED UNTIL I CLICK ON ITS TABICON
                    </IconTabFilter>

                </items>
            </IconTabBar>
        </Page>
    </pages>
</App>
</mvc:View>
```

What I need to do is, when the user searches something on the input1 field from view1, automatically call the second tab with the map and displays the address the user searched in the subview (lets call it view2).
The problem is, that i cant assign the input1 as autocomplete of the map in tab2, because that view is not created until i press into the tabfilter icon...

I think my only chance is creating a hidden div with a map in view1, assigning input1 to it, and when the user searches something, then "move" the map from view1 to a div on view2.
But I don't know how to achieve this.

I've tried creating a hidden component in view1 with htmlcode for a div, but if I set visible="false" the html code doesn't show, so I can't create the map. If I let the component visible, the map appears on view1 and works good, but I don't know how to "move" it to another view that hasn't been created.

I could get the map from view1 in the onInit FUnction on view2 using a getter function from the view1 controller if needed, but i still need to know how to do this three things:

1. Have a "temp" div in view1, that is not visible, but I can use it to create a map to assing input1 as autocomplete
2. When something is searched in the autocomplete input box, enable second tab of icontabbar and leave it visible.
3. Move the map from view1 to a div on view2, and keep the connection with input1 from view1.

Hope I was clear enough, this is driving me crazy!

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, your question is: "*how to establish connection between different isolated views?*"

Well, as you include the **view2** into **view1** declaratively within XML, it means that inner views (and corresponding controllers) will be created in a scope of the same **Component**, meaning the **owner component** will be shared among them. This statement gives us the following opportunity:

as the controller of **view1** and **view2** shares the same component: "*this.getOwnerComponent()*", you can establish connection between 2 views (corresponding controllers) via the events, that will be fired on the shared component object:

View1.controller (JS):

```
onSuggestSelected: function () {
    ---------
    var oComponent = this.getOwnerComponent();
    oComponent.fireEvent("view1:suggestValue", {foo: "bar"});
}
```

View2.controller (JS):

```
onInit: function () {
    var oComponent = this.getOwnerComponent();
    oComponent.attachEvent("view1:suggestValue", function (oParams) {
        var sSuggestValueFromView1 = oParams.foo;
        // do some logic here
    });
}
```

By this way, you can transmit a message from **view2** to **view1** when the **view2** is activated/rendered/whatever and **view1** can tell the **view2** to use a certain parameter for searching.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and your time!. I think i wasn't clear enough, what i need, is to "link" field Input1 in view1, with a component in view2. The problem is, that view2 doesn't exist when the app starts. It gets created when you switch to the tab that contains it.. I think is something by default in UI5. That's why i think i need to save my map in view1 in some aux var, and then switch to view2 when the user "uses" input1 and searches some address.

Comment: But what's the problem? You enter the data in input, then once you open the VIew2, this view tells the view1 "please give me the input value", then the map will be updated

Comment: The problem is the way in which Autcomplete from google maps api works. You need to asign the Autocomplete functions to the Input, and it must be asigned to a map to be able to search for addresses. 
So, i first need to create a map, then assign the input1(with the autocomplete functionality) to the map. The problem is that, until view2 is called, i don't have the map object that goes in that view, so i don't understand how can i "link" input1(with the autocomplete) to the map in a view that doesn't exist yet..

Comment: I've just updated my question with the full view1 code for some more clarity!